# Remove unwanted rows in worksheet

Tags: excel, vba

I'm looking for a code to delete unused cells that I can input into a code I have already written.

I have 2 sheets on my workbook, one is a quote and the other is a scope of supply. I have a macro set up to copy certain areas of the scope of supply depending on the drop down selection on the quote sheet. For example if "Timber Frame" is selected on the quote, the macro will then copy the scope included in a Timber frame quote and paste it under the quote. Only issue is, I have some smaller scopes than others so therefore the copy selection is smaller, as I have left the cells blank on the "quote" sheet to compensate for the biggest scope that would be copied.

I was looking to write something into my macro to remove the empty cells between my copied data and the terms and conditions which is under the copied data on my quote. Basically so my boss doesn't have to remove the empty rows himself when he saves the quote as they amount to a whole empty page...

If there is something that can be written under each "case" or whether it needs to be added at the end of the sub? OR, I change my code to insert the copied cells into the worksheet and move the rest of the workbook down, rather than have the cells just copied into already blank cells? My code is as follows:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    If Intersect(Target, Range("D5")) Is Nothing Then Exit Sub
        Select Case Target.Value
            Case "Timber Frame (New Build)"
                Sheets("Scope of Supply").Range("A3:F72").Copy Sheets("Quote").Range("B35")
            Case "Timber Frame (Extension)"
                Sheets("Scope of Supply").Range("H3:M72").Copy Sheets("Quote").Range("B35")
            Case "Eco Joists"
                Sheets("Scope of Supply").Range("O3:T26").Copy Sheets("Quote").Range("B35")
            Case "Truss Rafter"
                Sheets("Scope of Supply").Range("V3:AA33").Copy Sheets("Quote").Range("B35")
            Case "Eco Joists & Trusses"
                Sheets("Scope of Supply").Range("AC3:AH36").Copy Sheets("Quote").Range("B35")
            Case "Steel"
                Sheets("Scope of Supply").Range("AJ3:AO27").Copy Sheets("Quote").Range("B35")
    End Select
End Sub
```

**Edited**

I'm not sure the best way to describe it. I use a drop down selection on the "quote" page, depending on what is selected, it copies a table of data from the "scope of supply" page and pastes it into a set of blank cells that are on the "quote" tab (B35). Because some of the pasted tables are larger than others, I have had to have blank cells on my "quote" tab that fit the largest range. I've attached a [Print screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SAq9s.jpg) of my quote tab once I have the Eco-Joists table pasted into B36, as you can see there are a lot of blank cells underneath before it gets to our T's & C's. I'd ideally like to remove the blanks between the table and the terms depending on what drop down is used. As Timber Frame is the largest table pasted, it would not need blank cells removed as it uses all the blanks.

To answer some of the questions.

Will `lastrow` work if the pasted range is in the middle of a workbook?

The terms are starting in row 105. Column A is blank and just used as a border. Same with Column H, also a border. There is nothing beyond column H.

Comment: I must confess I could not exactly understand your problem. Can't you determine the exact range to be copied? Why should you define fixed ranges (in terms of rows and columns), if some of them may exceed the desired limits? Can you edit your question and show us a picture of one of the sheets where you copy from?

Comment: Have you tried sorting your data, then copying the sorted-data using the `lastRow` (found dynamically), which should remove blanks?  It appears that your issue is tied to all of the fixed ranged, e.g., `Sheets("Scope of Supply").Range("A3:F72").Copy`.

Comment: Are the *the terms and conditions* starting in row `105`? What's in the `A` column of the destination worksheet and is there something to the right of the `G` column? How does your code remove the old data with more rows when you pick a range with fewer rows? As a solution to your problem, I can see only to hide the empty rows. Did you have something else in mind?